# Typescript type narrowing too strict when using class method to update property

Tags: typescript

Is it intended that Typescript should be so strict on type narrowing when using a class method to update a property?  I'm not saying Typescript should somehow analyze what a method is doing, but it is a regular practice for class instance properties to be modified by methods.

I understand that changing `currentChar` from a normal property or a property getter to a method would solve this, but I think properties and getters are very valuable.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-u1entg?file=index.ts)

```
export class Parser {
    data = "abcdefg"
    currentIndex = 0

    get currentChar(): string {
        return this.data[this.currentIndex]
    }

    nextChar(): void {
        ++this.currentIndex
    }
}

(() => {
    const parser = new Parser()
    if (parser.currentChar !== "a") {
        return
    }

    const aChar: "a" = parser.currentChar // = type 'a', value 'a'
    parser.nextChar()
    const bChar: "a" = parser.currentChar // = type 'a', value 'b'

    if (parser.currentChar === "b") { // Error: This condition will always return 'false' since the types '"a"' and '"b"' have no overlap.
        console.log("current char really equals 'b'")
    }
})();
```

Comment: This is going to be one of those [trade-offs of control flow analysis](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998), where you are smarter than the compiler.  To fix this, the compiler would have to: figure out that the type of `parser.currentChar` should be widened after a call to `parser.nextChar()`, but not widen every variable after a call to every function (or narrowing would be useless), and not spend a lot of time making this sort of check (or compiler performance would be destroyed).  That's a tall order.

Comment: @jcalz we posted the same link 10s apart :))  if you make an answer out of that comment I'll delete mine, you were first :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a limitation of control flow analysis. Since you check the class property the type of the property will be narrowed by the check, and typescript will not clear this narrowing when a method is invoked.

You can read more about this [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998)